# Weird Android ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: android

I got a same network issue with this dude [[Link Here]](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131222/httpclient-often-times-out-using-wifi-is-going-fine-with-3g)

most network requirements working fine in 2g/3g mode, problem occurs only when connected via Wifi.

but everything work nicely on my iphone4,5/web browser , i can't figure out what's the problem with it.

so ,any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

here's the code

```
    //Code in HttpHelper.java
    public class HttpHelper{
        ..................
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);//295
        HttpResult result = new HttpResult();
        HttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);// line 298

        ..................
        public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }

        ..................
    }


    //Code in HttpResult.java
    public class HttpResult {
        public int code;
        public String response;

        public HttpResult(){
            this.code = HttpStatusCode.FAIL;
            this.response = null;
        }
    }
```

here's the log

```
10-30 11:18:18.672: W/System.err(945): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /188.151.209.58:80 timed out
10-30 11:18:18.682: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-30 11:18:18.682: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-30 11:18:18.682: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-30 11:18:18.682: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-30 11:18:18.682: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-30 11:18:18.682: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-30 11:18:18.687: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-30 11:18:18.687: W/System.err(945):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-30 11:18:18.687: W/System.err(945):  at my.package.name.manager.http.HttpHelper.getResponse(HttpHelper.java:298)
10-30 11:18:18.687: W/System.err(945):  at my.package.name.manager.http.HttpHelper.getData(HttpHelper.java:175)
10-30 11:18:18.687: W/System.err(945):  at my.package.name..util.ThreadUtil$TaskRunnable.run(ThreadUtil.java:209)
10-30 11:18:18.687: W/System.err(945):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-30 11:18:18.687: W/System.err(945):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-30 11:18:18.692: W/System.err(945):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

i tried to using androidhttpclient/apache.httpclient/basic-http-client...etc,eventually they throw me a timeout exception both

Comment: Post the code block and any error related to that otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: codes ready here, thanks for your reply

Comment: Are your iphones and android device same wifi network? make sure your url is correct and your wifi is connecting to the Internet. Set timeout abit longer to make sure, maybe 10s or 15s. Those are possible checking steps.

Comment: Am not able to open the URL (Ip address) in browser, I guess its not public. But if it is public then problem is with the server. You just need to handle time out exception in your app.

Comment: @user2652394 yeah,it's the same network and iphone work fine,android goes timeout often, currently timeout duration is 30 sec,still throw me a timeout exception even set up to 60 sec

Comment: Then consider `http` or `https` case, that's the last thing I can suggest you to look up to. Cheers!

Comment: @2-Stroker Sure,it's public,fast and accessible on any browser, the most important things that i worry about is the stability,btw thanks 4 your reply

Comment: @user2652394 worth to think about it ,have a nice day bro!

Comment: You can check and turn off firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use the internet permission in your manifest, and the link is correct, and maybe it will happen because of network traffic, those are the common possible 3 issues for your case.

Comment: ty dude, this happened after i change my ISP provider, it never happen before, which mean it's server's fault not android client?

Comment: i'am not really clear,it's just simply http request,i haven't specify any option yet

Comment: I meant third option i specified in my answer :)

Comment: perhaps,but iphone goes fine at the same time,it's freaky